Desktop blank and no icons in Lubuntu minimal from ubuntu server
I have developed a cloud-init autoinstallation procedure to install Lubuntu from an Ubuntu server ova from cloud images and do some customizations.
However I have some issues.
The process, I have run it manually is:

Install ubuntu-server
execute apt install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop

The weird thing is that if I take ubuntu-server-22.04 as the base OVA file the installation procedure is perfect. However when I take ubuntu-server-24.04 as the base OVA I get the following login screen and desktop environment.


As you can see the login screen doesnt have the default top bar or wallpaper. In the desktop the icons are not initialized by default (I have to do it manually using the menu Preferences -> LxQT Settings -> Appearence and even in that case some stuff if missing).
What is the problem? What packages do I have to include in 24.04 that where available in 22.04 version?
Thanks.
Edit: For the problem with the login page I have found that I have to also install lubuntu-artwork package. Still working on the icons theme, as when I enable adwaita from the menus, for example the sound icon is not displayed.
Answer: I will try to post the answer when possible. But here is what I have finally done.
Due to the change in lubuntu-desktop packages, some of the additional ones are not installed by default. Therefore the new installation procedure is:
$ apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop
$ apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-grub-theme 
$ apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends papirus-icon-theme fonts-ubuntu

This way the look and feel is similar to lubuntu-minimal installation, but including less packages (specially those linked to other GTK themes, etc.)
Besides, the GTK 2 theme is pointing to Arc-Darker and GTK3 to Breeze. Those packages can be also installed.

Lubuntu 22.04 LTS didn't have a minimal install option only; the minimal option only installs the base LXQt desktop as per Lubuntu documentation (24.04 & later). Your --no-install-recommends is causing you to get the minimal install option; ie. LXQt desktop or base desktop only as expected & documented. Refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/lubuntu-desktop for what you're excluding if interested.
